# How can I split a list of strings to display each word individually?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

At the moment I have a function which returns a list of strings. It takes a word from a view and then I would like to return to the view after the function displaying the individual words in different text boxes. However, I will not know how many words will be returned as I don't know how many the user will enter. It's only for improving my skills so it will be less than five. I have looked this up and haven't really found any results which help. I thought about splitting it up on the view itself which could work or even in my ViewModel and then returning that to the view. However, like I said. I can't simply put down three text boxes as I don't know for sure how many words will be entered. Can anybody help? I have posted the two areas below where I think I can split the list. Thank you.

View:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Split Result</h2>
    <!-- Wont work. Fix tomorrow. Split array-->
    <label>Split Words</label>
    <%: Html.TextBox("txtEncodeResult", Model.SplitWords)%>

</asp:Content>
```

Model:

```
      Function Split(inSentence) As List(Of String)

            '
            ' Get the posted information from the form
            Dim sSentence As String = inSentence
            '
            ' Create a list of string to put the sentene in and create a new instance of it
            Dim sSplitWords As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            '
            ' Find the position of the first space in sSentence
            Dim iPos As Integer
            iPos = InStr(sSentence, " ")

            'Find the length of the sentence
            Dim iLen As Integer
            iLen = Len(sSentence)

            '
            ' Create the remaining length
            Dim iRemainingLength As Integer = 0

            '
            ' Create sProp as string and set sProp to equal sSentence
            Dim sProp As String = ""
            sProp = sSentence

            '
            'Do while the position is not equal to 0
            Do While iPos <> 0

                '
                ' Find the left most characters from the position - 1 in sSentence  and then set this string as sProp
                sProp = Left(sSentence, iPos - 1)

                '
                ' Add the first word to the List
                sSplitWords.Add(sProp)

                '
                ' Find the new remaining length
                iRemainingLength = iLen - iPos

                '
                ' Get the rest of the sentence minus the word which has already been taken away.
                sSentence = sSentence.Substring(iPos, iRemainingLength)

                '
                ' Find the new position of the space in sSentence
                iPos = InStr(sSentence, " ")

                '
                ' Find the length of sSentence
                iLen = Len(sSentence)

                '
                'Loop while the condition is true
            Loop
            If iPos = 0 Then
                sSplitWords.Add(sSentence)
            End If
            '
            ' Return the array
            Return sSplitWords
        End Function
```

Like I said, I am simply improving my programming skills so it is very basic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *dramatically* reduce the code in your `Split` function, to one line in fact

```
Function Split(inSentence) As List(Of String)
    Return (inSentence ?? "").Split(" ").ToList();
End Function
```

Then in your view (assuming you are passing the list as the model) you can generate a new text box per word

```
@For Dim i as Integer = 0 To Model.Count-1
    @: Html.TextBox("tb" & i.ToString(), Model[i])
Next
```

Comment: I know I can. But the company I work for use Instr etc and they would like to keep me familiar with it. I understand split/join etc and can use them but they'd like me to use the other Vb functions

Comment: @AndrewKilburn not sure why your company is adamant you write *more* code to do what you can do in one line (and more than likely more efficiently).